# Launching husky_gazebo from another launch file with a different world

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm  trying to launch the husky_gazebo simulation (version 0.4.4) from another launch file and loading it in the Robocup world. The simulation runs successfully but the Robocup world isn't loaded.

Here is the code written in my launch file:

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="$(find husky_gazebo)/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

If instead I run directly from the terminal the following line:

```
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_empty_world.launch world_name:=worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world
```

then it works. I don't have any related error or warning shown in the terminal at launch (some PID gains no set but I also get this when launching with the line above in the terminal).

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363586/launching--husky_gazebo-from-another-launch-file-with-a-different-world/) by [Malkecero](https://answers.ros.org/users/61062/malkecero/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I ran into the exact same problem and solved it by changing the launch file as follows:

```
<launch>
    <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/husky_empty_world.launch">
        <arg name="world_name" value="/usr/share/gazebo-9/worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

I think the issue was caused by the fact that `worlds/robocup14_spl_field.world` is not located under `husky_gazebo`, but rather under `/usr/share/gazebo-9`.

I hope it applies to your situation too.

PS: Attending ETHZ ROS Course Programming for Robotics? ;)

---

Originally posted by [Mik_Ferrari](https://answers.ros.org/users/66534/mik_ferrari/) with karma: 26 on 2020-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Malkecero](https://answers.ros.org/users/61062/malkecero/) on 2021-01-23**:
I just went back today to this old piece of code and tried yours, it works! Thanks!

I was indeed following the ETHZ ROS Course ;)